# Remove the last element in the json

Tags: javascript, jquery, json

I want to remove the last element from the json.I have the object username,Geo,status,month,week2.
I want to remove week2 in my json

```js
const response = [{
    Username: "Denisse Morales",
    Geo: "NSU",
    Status: "Reaches",
    month: "May",
    Week2: 2
},
{
    Username: "Chandra Jeevan J",
    Geo: "US East",
    Status: "Reaches",
    month: "May",
    Week2: 1
},
{
    Username: "Amy Khalil",
    Geo: "US West",
    Status: "Reaches",
    month: "May",
    Week2: 2
},
{
    Username: "Ashuwinth Panneer",
    Geo: "Europe",
    Status: "Reaches",
    month: "June",
    Week2: 1
},
{
    Username: "John Joshuva",
    Geo: "Europe",
    Status: "Reaches",
    month: "May",
    Week2: 3
},
{
    Username: "Jose Alberto",
    Geo: "Europe",
    Status: "Reaches",
    month: "April",
    Week2: 2
},
{
    Username: "Dhivya Muthusamy",
    Geo: "Europe",
    Status: "Reaches",
    month: "June",
    Week2: 10
},
{
    Username: "Faizan Mohammed",
    Geo: "Middle East",
    Status: "Reaches",
    month: "May",
    Week2: 3
},
{
    Username: "Jaison Clinton",
    Geo: "NSU",
    Status: "Reaches",
    month: "April",
    Week2: 9
}];

console.log(response.splice(0, -1));
```

expected

```
[{
    Username: "Denisse Morales",
    Geo: "NSU",
    Status: "Reaches",
    month: "May"
},
{
    Username: "Chandra Jeevan J",
    Geo: "US East",
    Status: "Reaches",
    month: "May"
},
{
    Username: "Amy Khalil",
    Geo: "US West",
    Status: "Reaches",
    month: "May"
},
{
    Username: "Ashuwinth Panneer",
    Geo: "Europe",
    Status: "Reaches",
    month: "June"
},
{
    Username: "John Joshuva",
    Geo: "Europe",
    Status: "Reaches",
    month: "May"
},
{
    Username: "Jose Alberto",
    Geo: "Europe",
    Status: "Reaches",
    month: "April"
},
{
    Username: "Dhivya Muthusamy",
    Geo: "Europe",
    Status: "Reaches",
    month: "June"
},
{
    Username: "Faizan Mohammed",
    Geo: "Middle East",
    Status: "Reaches",
    month: "May"
},
{
    Username: "Jaison Clinton",
    Geo: "NSU",
    Status: "Reaches",
    month: "April"
}]
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Loop through the array ([`[].forEach`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/forEach)), use [`delete`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/delete) to remove `Week2`;

```js
const response = [{Username: "Denisse Morales", Geo: "NSU", Status: "Reaches", month: "May", Week2: 2}, {Username: "Chandra Jeevan J", Geo: "US East", Status: "Reaches", month: "May", Week2: 1}, {Username: "Amy Khalil", Geo: "US West", Status: "Reaches", month: "May", Week2: 2}, {Username: "Ashuwinth Panneer", Geo: "Europe", Status: "Reaches", month: "June", Week2: 1}, {Username: "John Joshuva", Geo: "Europe", Status: "Reaches", month: "May", Week2: 3}, {Username: "Jose Alberto", Geo: "Europe", Status: "Reaches", month: "April", Week2: 2}, {Username: "Dhivya Muthusamy", Geo: "Europe", Status: "Reaches", month: "June", Week2: 10}, {Username: "Faizan Mohammed", Geo: "Middle East", Status: "Reaches", month: "May", Week2: 3}, {Username: "Jaison Clinton", Geo: "NSU", Status: "Reaches", month: "April", Week2: 9}];

response.forEach((r) => delete r.Week2);
console.log(response);
```

This approach could be shortened using the [ES6 destructuring spreading](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/Destructuring_assignment);

```
response.map(({Week2, ...r}) => r);
```

```js
let response = [{Username: "Denisse Morales", Geo: "NSU", Status: "Reaches", month: "May", Week2: 2}, {Username: "Chandra Jeevan J", Geo: "US East", Status: "Reaches", month: "May", Week2: 1}, {Username: "Amy Khalil", Geo: "US West", Status: "Reaches", month: "May", Week2: 2}, {Username: "Ashuwinth Panneer", Geo: "Europe", Status: "Reaches", month: "June", Week2: 1}, {Username: "John Joshuva", Geo: "Europe", Status: "Reaches", month: "May", Week2: 3}, {Username: "Jose Alberto", Geo: "Europe", Status: "Reaches", month: "April", Week2: 2}, {Username: "Dhivya Muthusamy", Geo: "Europe", Status: "Reaches", month: "June", Week2: 10}, {Username: "Faizan Mohammed", Geo: "Middle East", Status: "Reaches", month: "May", Week2: 3}, {Username: "Jaison Clinton", Geo: "NSU", Status: "Reaches", month: "April", Week2: 9}];

response = response.map(({ Week2, ...rest }) => rest);
console.log(response);
```

---

If you really need the 'last' key, you can get it by converting to a array;

**Note**: Order is not guaranteed, so you could get unexpected results if `Week2` is not the last prop

```js
const response = [{Username: "Denisse Morales", Geo: "NSU", Status: "Reaches", month: "May", Week2: 2}, {Username: "Chandra Jeevan J", Geo: "US East", Status: "Reaches", month: "May", Week2: 1}, {Username: "Amy Khalil", Geo: "US West", Status: "Reaches", month: "May", Week2: 2}, {Username: "Ashuwinth Panneer", Geo: "Europe", Status: "Reaches", month: "June", Week2: 1}, {Username: "John Joshuva", Geo: "Europe", Status: "Reaches", month: "May", Week2: 3}, {Username: "Jose Alberto", Geo: "Europe", Status: "Reaches", month: "April", Week2: 2}, {Username: "Dhivya Muthusamy", Geo: "Europe", Status: "Reaches", month: "June", Week2: 10}, {Username: "Faizan Mohammed", Geo: "Middle East", Status: "Reaches", month: "May", Week2: 3}, {Username: "Jaison Clinton", Geo: "NSU", Status: "Reaches", month: "April", Week2: 9}];

response.forEach((r) => {

  // Last key
  const keys = Object.keys(r);
  const lastKey = keys[keys.length - 1];
   
  // Remove
  delete r[lastKey];
});

console.log(response);
```

Answer (score 1):

This can easily be done with [array.map()](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/map) and the [rest operator](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/Destructuring_assignment)

```js
const response = [{Username: "Denisse Morales", Geo: "NSU", Status: "Reaches", month: "May", Week2: 2}, {Username: "Chandra Jeevan J", Geo: "US East", Status: "Reaches", month: "May", Week2: 1}, {Username: "Amy Khalil", Geo: "US West", Status: "Reaches", month: "May", Week2: 2}, {Username: "Ashuwinth Panneer", Geo: "Europe", Status: "Reaches", month: "June", Week2: 1}, {Username: "John Joshuva", Geo: "Europe", Status: "Reaches", month: "May", Week2: 3}, {Username: "Jose Alberto", Geo: "Europe", Status: "Reaches", month: "April", Week2: 2}, {Username: "Dhivya Muthusamy", Geo: "Europe", Status: "Reaches", month: "June", Week2: 10}, {Username: "Faizan Mohammed", Geo: "Middle East", Status: "Reaches", month: "May", Week2: 3}, {Username: "Jaison Clinton", Geo: "NSU", Status: "Reaches", month: "April", Week2: 9}];
 
const changed = response.map(({ Week2, ...rest }) => rest);

console.log(changed);
```

Answer (score 1):

You should iterate over the array and remove the property. An elegant way is not mutating the original array.

```js
response.map((item) => {Username: item.Username, Geo: item.Geo, Status: item.Status, Month: item.Month})
```

Comment: Minor correction: Instead of `(item) => {` it should be `(item) => ({... })`

Comment: true, thanks, I've missed the `return` keyword or the `()`

Answer (score 0):

Easier with ES6, it will deconstruct each object and will a create new one

```
const newArray = response.map(({Week2, ...keepIt}) => keepIt);

console.log(newArray);
```